# problem to set Android toolbar overFlow menu style (rounded corner with stroke line)

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-styles, overflow-menu

what I am trying to do is to get a simple menu with rounded corner and stroke line like this:[image: my final goal]

but what i am getting is this:

[image: what i get]

first I made a shape whit ripple in drawable (drop_down_back_0.xml):

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#C54747">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary"  android:width="1dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

then i used it in a style:

```
   <style name="toolbarMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/drop_down_back_0</item>
    </style>
```

finaly I used the style in my activity_layout.xml:

```
.
.
.
 <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#526C98"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:titleTextColor="#fff"
        app:popupTheme="@style/toolbarMenuStyle" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the OverflowMenu you can define in your app theme the `actionOverflowMenuStyle` attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/custompopupOverflowMenu</item>
</style>
```

With:

```
  <style name="custompopupOverflowMenu" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/my_mtrl_popupmenu_background</item>   
  </style>
```

where the background is something like:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorSurface"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>

    <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" 
                  android:width="1dp"/>

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:top="8dp"/>

</shape>
```

[image]